# is there any class for use istio part of quarkus operator sdk

Tags: quarkus, istio, istio-gateway, istio-operator

I am writing k8s operator for simple deployment.
i am using VS(virtual service) from `istio`. Can i write/create automatically VS as part of my operator
NOTE: I am **using quarks operatorsdk**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can inject a `KubernetesClient` into your code and create any resource (if your operator has the permissions to perform the operation in the `Role`). See https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes-client